# Video carousel using owl.carousel.js is not working

Tags: javascript, html, video, owl-carousel

Video carousel is not displayed in html page while trying to use owl.carousel.js. Anyone please help me to setup a video carousel in my website.

```js
 $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        items:1,
        merge:true,
        loop:true,
        margin:10,
        video:true,
        lazyLoad:true,
        center:true,
        responsive:{
            480:{
                items:2
            },
            600:{
                items:3
            }
        }
    })
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item-video" data-merge="3"><a class="owl-video" href="https://vimeo.com/23924346"></a></div>
    <div class="item-video" data-merge="1"><a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JpxsRwnRwCQ"></a></div>
    <div class="item-video" data-merge="2"><a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBu_jxT1PkA"></a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you get any error? also why do you set 600:{items:4} if you got only 3 items?

Comment: Hi, Its a typo. Havn't got any errors and no contents are displayed.